# Accessing Private Member Data and Function

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have a quick question for an upcoming final. Are private member data and functions only accessible by the constructor?

Answer and elaboration appreciated.

Here's the question and answer that prompted me to come to you guys:

**EDIT:**

> 5) Be able to determine when a statement is an invalid attempt to access private member variables or functions.
>           - This is a give away, private functions and variables can only be accessed in the constructor.

So this is wrong?

Comment: No, private members of a class can be accessed by any of the other members of that class. Are you thinking of initializing `const` members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's plain wrong.

From the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 (E), §11.0/1):

> A member of a class can be
>       - private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared.

It says *members*, not *constructor*.

Answer (score 1):

Private members of a class will be accessible to any of that classes methods. A point to consider is static member functions which do not have a `this` pointer and only have access to static member variables. Friend functions and Friend classes are also able to access a classes private member variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can access private members from anywhere inside the class, but not from other classes or other subclasses.

Comment: Unless the other class in question is declared as a `friend`

Comment: Ah, yes, I thought we were talking about Java but it's c++.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are accessible from everywhere within the object, its just not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach them inside the object itself, not only constructor.

And also you should have get and set methods to get or set it from outside the object in case you wonder how to be able.